# Unattended authentication through Azure Powershell for Resource Manager

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have a load of Azure Powershell deployment scripts that are triggered by the build server after the completion of a build which work perfectly - I use the Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile (which is securely stored locally) to log into Azure unattended.

I now need to extend these to include management of Sql Azure Servers, Elastic Pools and Databases.

These, however, are part of the [Azure Resource Manager cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx) which have a different method of authentication.

I've found these articles:

- [Authenticating a Service Principal with Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/)
- [Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/)
- [Using Windows Azure Active Directory to Authenticate the Management Libraries](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/using-windows-azure-active-directory-to-authenticate-the-management-libraries))

but all appear to *require you to enter your credentials* at some stage at the process.  The second link above explicitly states:

> The AzureResourceManager module requires Add-AzureAccount. A Publish Settings file is not sufficient.

I've tried (just to see what happens) switching to the Resource Manager with `Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager` and then just executing one of the cmdlets, such as `Get-AzureResourceGroup -Name "blah"` but I just get an error of

> Get-AzureResourceGroup : AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is not present or provided in an invalid format.

I am quite happy to set up an AD Application, manually, **once**, through the portal and then provide my scripts with the relevant Application ID or whatever is required.  I just need it to be unattended so that my build can deploy!

**Can anyone tell me how I go about making an unattended script to use these Azure Resource Manager cmdlets through Powershell?**

Comment: I think I may have found the answer... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/25/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post gives full details of how to do this.  Basically you embed your powershell scripts with the username and password of your AD user.

- [Unattended authentication to Azure Management APIs with Azure Active Directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/25/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory.aspx)

But be aware that if, like me, you wish to combine calls to the AzureResourceManager *and* AzureServiceManagement modes (using `Switch-AzureMode`) then you must use `Add-AzureAccount -Credential <credentials>` and also `Remove-AzureAccount -Name <username>` otherwise some of the AzureServiceManagement mode cmdlets cease to work.